# Interface as Parameter in List Argument c#

Tags: c#

I have a custom interface.  I am design a function that takes an argument which is a list.  When I pass an argument that is a list of a class that meets this interface, I get an error.  Example code below:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        TestClass A = new TestClass();
        A.Name = "A";
        TestClass B = new TestClass();
        B.Name = "B";
        TestClassList aList = new TestClassList();

        aList.myList.Add(A);
        aList.myList.Add(B);

        PrintTestClass(aList.myList);


    }
    public static void PrintTestClass(List<ItestInterface> TestList)
    {
        foreach (ItestInterface i in TestList)
            Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
    }

}
interface ItestInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
class TestClass : ItestInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string otherVar { get; set; }

}
class TestClassList
{
    public List<TestClass> myList;

    public TestClassList()
    {
        myList = new List<TestClass>();
    }

}
```

Here, my calling of "PrintTestClass" calls an error that it cannot convert `List<TestClass>` to `List<ItestInterface>`.  I try to cast it, still doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create a 2nd class that implements `ITestInterface` and I I think you will see the problem. Every `TestClass` is a `ITestInterface` but not every `ITestInterface` has to be a `TestClass` so you can't safely put a ITestInterface in a list of TestClasses. The process of getting around this limitation is called "Covarance" and "Contravariance"

Comment: You can use public static void PrintTestClass(IEnumerable<ItestInterface> TestList) instead.

Comment: That's not what I'm doing.  I'm putting a List<TestClass> into a List<ItestInterface>.  I'm not putting a List<ItestInterface> into a List<TestClass>

Comment: @Xiaosu - that worked, but why?  What does changing List -> IEnumerable do?

Comment: @tmptplayer The `IEnumerable<T>` interface is declared as `IEnumerable<out T>` this `out` keyword makes it "Covariant" meaning that it says that it's generic type `T` will only be used in return types (so it only comes out of the interface) therefor it's safe to cast a `List<TestClass>` to a `IEnumerable<ITestInterface>` (since each `TestClass` is an `ITestInterface` we're guaranteed that everything comming out of the `IEnumerable` is an `ITestInterface`. However a `List` would also allow adding of an `ITestInterface` which you can't do on a `List<TestClass>`

Comment: @Knoop - Got it, thanks.  Essentially I had neglected the List write case and that the list is passed by reference not by value.